# Vuejs sidebar menu with subitems

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to create a sidebar menu dinamically with vuejs and vuenotify.

I have seen a sample on vuetify site using something as bellow.

The problem with this code, is that always shows the append-icon ">" on end of item title .

I´d like to show the append-icon ">", only if I have subittems. 
I have created an item called "Manuutenção" with subtitems. No other has subitems. 
Then, i´d like only "Manutençao" item or other(if I create with subitems") showing the ">".

Is possible fix it?

```
<v-list>
      <v-list-group
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.title"
        v-model="item.active"
        :prepend-icon="item.icon"
        no-action
      >
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </template>

        <v-list-item
          v-for="subItem in item.items"
          :key="subItem.title"
          link
          router
          :to="subItem.to"
        >
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>

export default {
  name: "DashboardCoreDrawer",
data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        icon: "mdi-view-dashboard",
        title: "Dashboard",
        to: "/",
      },
      {
        icon: "mdi-account",
        title: "Usuários",
        to: "/usuarios",
      },
      {
        title: "Clientes",
        icon: "mdi-map-marker",
        to: "/clientes",
      },
      {
        title: "Manutenção",
        icon: "mdi-clipboard-outline",
        to: "",
        items: [
          {
            title: "Convênios",
            icon: "mdi-clipboard-outline",
            to: "/convenios",
          },
          {
            title: "Planos",
            icon: "mdi-format-font",
            to: "/planos",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "Convênios",
        icon: "mdi-clipboard-outline",
        to: "/convenios",
      },
      {
        title: "Planos",
        icon: "mdi-format-font",
        to: "/planos",
      },
      {
        title: "Tabelas",
        icon: "mdi-chart-bubble",
        to: "/tabelas",
      },
      {
        title: "Atendimento",
        icon: "mdi-bell",
        to: "atendimentos",
      },
    ],
  }),
}
```

**Additional information:**
Is possible make adaptations to two or three submenu items. For sample:

```
items:[
{
        title: "Manutenção",
        icon: "mdi-clipboard-outline",
        to: "",
        items: [
          {
            title: "Convênios",
            icon: "mdi-clipboard-outline",
            to: "/convenios",
          },
          {
            title: "Planos",
            icon: "mdi-format-font",
            to: "",
            items: [
              {
                title: "Test1,
                icon: "mdi-chart-bubble",
                to: "/test1",
              },
              {
                title: "Test2",
                icon: "mdi-chart-bubble",
                to: "/test2",
              },
            ],
          },
]
```

Icon at "Planos"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main trick is to render v-list-group when item has subitems and v-list-item otherwise. See an example below:

```
<template>
    <v-list>
      <template v-for="item in items">
        <v-list-group
          :key="item.title"
          v-if="item.items !== undefined"
          v-model="item.active"
          no-action
        >
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-avatar left>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-avatar>

            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </template>

          <v-list-item
            v-for="subItem in item.items"
            :key="subItem.title"
            link
            router
            :to="subItem.to"
          >
            <v-list-item-avatar left>
              <v-icon>{{ subItem.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
        <v-list-item v-else :key="item.title" link router :to="item.to">
          <v-list-item-avatar left>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </template>
    </v-list>
</template>
```

Edited:

For a multilevel solution, basically, you have to create a component for list item and import it recursively into itself. Something like that:

mainlist.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-list>
      <list-item v-for="item in items" :item="item" :key="item.title">
      </list-item>
    </v-list>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DashboardCoreDrawer",
  components: {
    ListItem: () => import("./listitem.vue"),
  },
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        title: "Convênios",
        icon: "mdi-clipboard-outline",
        to: "/convenios",
      },
      {
        title: "Planos",
        icon: "mdi-format-font",
        items: [
          {
            title: "Test1",
            icon: "mdi-chart-bubble",
            items: [
              {
                title: "Test4",
                icon: "mdi-chart-bubble",
                to: "/test1",
              },
              {
                title: "Test5",
                icon: "mdi-chart-bubble",
                to: "/test2",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            title: "Test2",
            icon: "mdi-chart-bubble",
            to: "/test2",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```

listitem.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-list-group
      v-if="item.items !== undefined"
      v-model="item.active"
      no-action
      :sub-group="isSubGroup"
      :class="isSubGroup ? 'right-icon' : ''"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator>

        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>{{ item.title }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </template>
      <template v-for="subItem in item.items">
        <list-item :item="subItem" :is-sub-group="true" :key="subItem.title">
        </list-item>
      </template>
    </v-list-group>
    <v-list-item v-else link router :to="item.to">
      <v-list-item-avatar left>
        <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-avatar>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "listitem",
  props: ["item", "isSubGroup"],
  components: {
    ListItem: () => import("./listitem.vue"),
  },
};
</script>
<style>
 .right-icon .v-list-group__header {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It solve the first level problem. I have put an additional info in the question aboout multi-levels. Is possible to adapt the code to multi-level?

Comment: I've update my answer for a multilevel solution. Check if its working

Comment: Amazing..... At "Planos' item I have sublevel. Is possible to put the triangle icon to right side? I attached a picture

Comment: I've seen the issue you're talking about, but unfortunately this is the layout provided by vuetify for nested lists without options for changing it. You can see it on their official page https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#nested-lists. Sorry.

Comment: How about use a css style? Is possible?

Comment: You can append a class to subgroup list, and reverse the direction of displaying the elements, since the layout is rendering first the activator icon. You can see in the updated answer. But it seems too hacky for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. It´s ok to me.